# Prevent link to open in PWA

Tags: hyperlink, window, progressive-web-apps, postmessage

A have multiple web applications that are all PWA. From application A, I need to open application B in a window which allows me to navigate to any of the other applications and make a selection, which I then send back to application A by using 'window.opener.postMessage'. This works great on desktop. It opens a single new window, in which I can navigate my whole application suite and it stays in that window. On mobile however, every link to another (pwa) application is automatically opened within a new PWA 'window' which is fine at every other moment, but not when you want to send back data to the originating opener. Is there a way to prevent a link to a PWA application to open the PWA application, and instead just open in this same browser window?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?